# Can i see only of my debug logs in salesforce?

Tags: salesforcedx, debug-logs

In my org there are tons of users. When i want to see my debug logs, i see thousands of debug logs which is not relevant for me, what should i do to check only of mine logs?

Comment: Generally speaking, the more details, the better. If you've tried to research this issue or work around it already, sharing your research and results will generally lead to your question being better received. That said, I don't think there's a ton of information out there on this specific topic. Are you able to execute queries (logs are stored in the `ApexLog` object, and it is queryable)? Is it possible for you to otherwise reduce the number of users being logged at any given point in time? The "thousands of logs" bit makes it sound like there is a lot of noise that can be eliminated.

Comment: If you want to use the UI to view the logs, you can just create a new view and set the Requested By First Name and Requested By Last Name as your name.  That should filter only your requested debug logs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can see only your debug log. For this, you have to set your debug log in debug log

[image: Debug Log]

For more details you can read here : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5

Comment: Begging for upvotes and accepts is seen as rude behavior here, and I'd discourage you from making similar comments in the future.

Comment: This answer does not seem to adequately address the question at hand. OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question) is already seeing many debug logs and is trying to isolate their own. The issue is not with setting up a debug log of their own. As such, I've downvoted this answer.